# Android using onConfigurationChanged resets my listview scroll position

Tags: android, listview

In my app I have chat activity with listview. I decided to use onConfigurationChanged to retain this listview with messages, while user changes screen orientation. The problem is that scroll position is resetting every time. How I can keep my scroll position for listview.
In Manifest

```
<activity
            android:name=".ChatActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
/>
```

In activity

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        Log.d(TAG, "orientation changed");
        chatView.setSelection(scrollPosition);
    }
```

Comment: show your listview declaration of xml file

Answer (score 1):

Remove this:

```
chatView.setSelection(scrollPosition);
```

[Edit]

```
//Save state
Parcelable state = listView.onSaveInstanceState();

//Restore state
listView.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
```

[Edit2]:

```
//Save
int index = mList.getFirstVisiblePosition();
View v = listView.getChildAt(0);
int top = (v == null) ? 0 : (v.getTop() - mList.getPaddingTop());

//Restore
listView.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
```

Comment: got this error
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Parcelable android.widget.AbsListView$SavedState.getSuperState()' on a null object reference
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onRestoreInstanceState(AbsListView.java:1871)
            at com.spalmalo.grouvi.app.ChatActivity.onConfigurationChanged(ChatActivity.java:192)` it happens when I try to call inRestoreInstanceState in onConfigurationChanged

Comment: I guess that state is not saved in onSaveInstanceState

Comment: tried to move scrollState assignment to onScrollStateChanged event, now not giving errors, but still resets listview position

Comment: I think we need some call to update the listView scroll.

Comment: What do you mean "some call"? I know for sure that onConfigurationChanged is called, but I don't understand why it's not setting scroll position in listview.

Comment: Can you try `Edit2` answer?

Comment: I tried Edit2, event tried to set manually numbers for setSelectionFromTop(). still same, resetting scrollPosition. Anyway thank you for your help.

Comment: Third one should work. Don't know why it is not working.

Comment: Normally listview.setSelection()(or setSelectionFromTop()) works in my code. But why it's not working in onConfigurationChanged, even though all data is kept confusing me.

Comment: The first EDIT with `listView.onSaveInstanceState()` was the only one that worked for me, and probably should be the accepted approach here.

Answer (score 0):

If you write chat, you probably added for listview transcript mode = ALWAYS_SCROLL

`msgListView.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);`

This mode scroll listview to bottom, after screen rotation.
Comment it and list position will remain after rotation.

Scroll mode you can change to forced movement to end of list, like below:

`chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
int pos = msgListView.getCount()-1;
msgListView.setSelection(pos);`